# Python NLTK not classify correctly even with correct informative features

Tags: python, nltk

I'm use NLTK to analyze a little dataset (1000 rows) of data from my system. All works as expected, buy when I try classify data, same strange happens. Look my **"show_most_informative_features"** result:

```
              execut = True             1114 : 1790   =     91.2 : 1.0
                  r$ = True             1114 : 1790   =     56.2 : 1.0
                pens = True             1114 : 1790   =     40.1 : 1.0
                 val = True             1114 : 1790   =     39.8 : 1.0
                 pag = True             1114 : 1790   =     28.5 : 1.0
              parcel = True             1114 : 1790   =     24.1 : 1.0
                real = True             1114 : 1790   =     24.1 : 1.0
            municípi = True             2049 : 1790   =     23.6 : 1.0
             aliment = True             1114 : 203    =     22.2 : 1.0
              veícul = True             2049 : 1790   =     22.1 : 1.0
                   é = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.5 : 1.0
               efetu = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.2 : 1.0
          palmas/to, = True             1114 : 1790   =     21.2 : 1.0
                rend = True             2049 : 1790   =     20.5 : 1.0
                cont = True              178 : 1790   =     19.9 : 1.0
```

This is my data for test:

```
['execut', 'r$', 'pen', 'val', 'pag']
```

I expected the result to be **1114**, because I use top 5 words with best match with this classification. Buy my classifier only classify all as "**1790"**. My code works with another dataset more simple, but using this dataset this no make sense.

If I `print prob_classify()` this is a result:

CODE:

```
def show_distribuicao():
  distribuicao = classificador.prob_classify(linha_teste_frase)

  for classe in distribuicao.samples():
      print("%s: %f" % (classe, distribuicao.prob(classe)))
```

RESULT:

```
178: 0.000000
1790: 1.000000
203: 0.000000
1114: 0.000000
2049: 0.000000
```

And my `qualificacao_id.value_counts()`:

```
1790    323
203     237
178     152
1114    147
2049    141
```

Any idea why this happens?